# Entity Framework Associations without primary key

Tags: entity-framework

I have come to the conclusion that I absolutely hate the Entity Framework designer!

I have two tables:

```
StockMovement
Warehouse
```

In `StockMovement` I have these columns:

```
MovementID - Primary Key
MovementType
RefNumber
StockID
WarehouseID
```

In `Warehouse` I have these columns:

```
WarehouseID
Code
Name
SiteID
```

Now, I thought this would be simple, but hey it's not...

I simply want to add a new association between the `WarehouseID` columns so that I can continue with my app.

I added a new association but every single time the Entity Framework designer throw different errors, saying first that I need to include the `MovementID` column. I include it then it complains about me linking the `MovementID` column to something else

All I want to do is to link `WarehouseID` in `StockMovements` with `WarehouseID` in `Warehouse`.

Any good suggestions please?

Comment: A suggestion would be to move to Code First, where you can set up the associations with the fluent api?

Comment: *without primary key* is a bad design to begin with - maybe you need to first stick to proven database design principles (*if it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table*) before you start complaining about tools that suck ....

Comment: Make `Warehouse.WarehouseId` a primary key and then try

Answer (score 0):

Can WareHouse.WareHouseID not be a primary key?

Without Primary keys (I believe) you can't save data, that and you don't a have a primary key so I'm assuming it's a view therefore I'm assuming this is just read only. If that's the case just tell EF that the Warehouse.WarehouseID is a primary it'll not affect reading, it won't care about integrity as I assume that you know that'll be ok because of your forced join.

Comment: thanks for all you rcomments. WarehouseID is indeed a Primaqry key inside Warehouse. I removed the entity key propertu for MovementID in StockMovement and added the association; now i get two errors : Must include mapping for all key properties ( StockMovement.MovementID ) and : Each of the following columns in StockMovement is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties - StockMovement.WarehouseID is mapped to <StockMovementWarehouse.Warehouse.WarehouseID, StockMovementWarehouse.StockMovement.WarehouseID>  my question now is: how do I remove these mappings? Thanks in advance

Comment: can anyone help. i simply do not know what to do

Comment: OK, Progress. I had to manually edit the Edmx file in XML to get rid of the first error. Now I still do not know how to fix this error : Each of the following columns in StockMovement is mapped to multiple 

conceptual side properties - StockMovement.WarehouseID is mapped to <StockMovementWarehouse.Warehouse.WarehouseID, 

StockMovementWarehouse.StockMovement.WarehouseID.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not without knowing what you did to your XML. I would suggest starting again, or at least creating a new, temporary EF view and dragging in the tables from your view, create the associations and then in the properties of the warehouseID set it to primary.